Can sihr/jinns make my partner beat me up and start taking drugs?
I have been told that my husband has been affected by sihr. I came home one day and i caught him taking drugs so i confronted him. He chased me in the house while i held my daughter and kept punching me in my face and hitting me. He smashed my phone and started swearing vile swears infront of my children about me. His family say its not him its the sihr but is it even possible for sihr to make you act like that or are they making excuses?

No matter if he is bewitched to take the drugs or does it out of his own will: he is out of mind and, in this current state, a danger not only to you but also to your daughter. Believe me, I know what I am talking about. Seek refuge so he can not harm neither you nor your daughter. Ask a mufti to confirm your decision, and ask his  advice what to do next. Urgently. If someone takes drugs and beats up his wife, he is also a danger to the public as such, and should be cured, whether of shir or only of drugs. Inshallah, your daughter and you will be safe.
